# How to use a backquoted scala identifier in java?

Tags: java, scala, interop

I'm working on a project in Java/Scala that analyse Java code. In my scala code I have :

```
package p{
   object NodeKind{
      // In real code they are not Int but this is good enough for the example
      val `class` = 0 
      val interface = 0
   }
}
```

And I need to access it from Java

```
class MyJavaClass{
     void m(){
        /* ... */
        int value = p.NodeKind.//how can I access to `class` or interface ?
        /* ... */
     }
}
```

For now I have settled with Brian Agnew solution, I added a field

```
  val classKind = `class`
```

in my scala object and I can access it with `p.nodeKind.classKind()` in my java code but I would really prefer to know the compilation (mangling?) rules for `class` and interface to access it directly.

Comment: I don't think he has, has he ?

Comment: @p3rand0r wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: you have right , i made a mistake

Comment: following your advice, I posted the qestion on stackexchange:
https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238090/how-to-use-a-backquoted-scala-identifier-in-java

Comment: And there they tell me that the question really belongs here :s

Comment: @user45000 the distinction is that this isn't a design or algorithm question - its a question of specific code (that your question now has). If you look at the [help/on-topic] of each site ([P.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), this falls into the "a specific programming problem" in the on topic of SO and "implementation issues, such as code fixes" of the off topic on P.SE.  Thus, this is the best place for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your two options may be:

1. create an accessor method within your Scala class
2. create an accessor method within your Java class using reflection to find that field and read it

e.g.

```
class A {
   val class = 1
   def clazz = class
}
```